# Passing and Returning Data between Pages C# Xaml

Tags: c#, data-binding, parameter-passing

I am following the Petzold's tutorial. However, I can't get my algorithm to work properly.

I create a class for the purpose of passing data between two pages:

```
public class PassData
{
   public object Data { set; get; }
}
```

Then, I include my PassData object as second argument to Navigate: 
(MainPage.xaml.cs)

```
private void Button2Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        // Create PassData object
        PassData passData = new PassData();

        // Set the InitializeData property from the ListBox
        passData.Data = firstElement.Content;

        // Pass that object to Navigate
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Menu2), passData);

    }
```

Then, within Menu2 I try to initialize the buttons name with passed object:

```
// pulling data from first page selection
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs args)
    {
        // Get the object passed as the second argument to Navigate
        PassData passData = args.Parameter as PassData;

        // Use that to initilize the button
        firstElement.Content = args;
    }
```

`firstElement` is my button's alias.

When I run the code, on the MainPage I click on the ListBox Item, it is assigned to firstElement.Content, I then navigate to Menu2 page, and all I get in place of the button's content is: `Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs` .

----- SOLUTION -----

I have resolved the problem by doing as follows:

Within Menu2.xaml.cs instead of `firstElement.Content = args;` I put

```
firstElement.Content = passData.Data;

            base.OnNavigatedTo(args);
```

Answer (score 0):

Within Menu2.xaml.cs instead of `firstElement.Content = args;` I put

```
firstElement.Content = passData.Data;

            base.OnNavigatedTo(args);
```

This resolves the problem and the data is being passed between two pages.